# How to simplify handling with nested ifelse() structures in base R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm facing nested `ifelse()` structures:

```
df1$var <- ifelse(x < a, u, ifelse(x < b, v, ifelse(x < c, w, ...)))
```

whereby the `u, v, w, ...`s are actually *functions*.

A dumbed down working example would be

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = rbinom(100, 5, .5))
df1$y <- ifelse(x == 1, "s", ifelse(x == 2, "t", 
                                    ifelse(x == 3, "u", ifelse(x == 4, "v", "w"))))
```

I presume there could be ideally a ***base R*** method (**for sake of speed**) to simplify such code; eventually a function as

```
rave.ifelse(x, 1=s, 2=t, ...)
```

I took a glance at `cut(x, 5)` but it confused me from this point of view.

*Note:* Values of `x` could be either numbers or factors, `==` could also be any logical operator and the `s, t, ...` are actually *functions*.

***edit:***

*Note:* The number of `ifelse()`s is known and large. The solution really should fit to the `df1$var <- ifelse(x < a, u, ifelse(x < b, v, ifelse(x < c, w, ...)))` situation, when the `u, v, w, ...`s are functions, e.g. `u=sample(0:9, 1), v=runif(1),...`. It should not be significantly slower than `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`case_when`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/case_when) from the `dplyr` library:

```
df1$y <- case_when(
    x == 1 ~ "s",
    x == 2 ~ "t",
    x == 3 ~ "u",
    x == 4 ~ "v",
    TRUE ~ "w"
)
```

Note that the final case above (`TRUE`) is the blanket else condition which will catch all cases not matching any earlier conditions.

Comment: Since this is much faster than the other solutions, I wouldn't absolutely resist on base R (ifelse is still 3x faster though). But apparently it is designed for characters. When I want to apply a function as stated, e.g. try `df1$x == 3 ~ rnorm(1)`, I have to `df1$x == 3 ~ as.character(rnorm(1))`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you insist on base R, here are two possibilities:

Define a mapping `data.frame`:

```
# Define mapping
map <- cbind.data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA),
    y = c("s", "t", "u", "v", "w"));
```

Method 1: `match` entries from `map` to `df1`.

```
# match entries
df1$y <- map[match(df1$x, map$x), 2];
df1$y[is.na(df1$y2)] <- "w";
```

Method 2: Loop through all mappings, and replace using direct indexing:

```
# for loop
df1$y <- factor("w", levels = map$y);
for (i in 1:nrow(map)) df1$y[df1$x == map$x[i]] <- map$y[i];
```

Output:

```
tail(df1);
#    x y
#95  4 v
#96  1 s
#97  4 v
#98  2 t
#99  4 v
#100 1 s
```

Note, the second method will also work for inequalities.

---

### Sample data

```
set.seed(2017);
df1 <- data.frame(x = rbinom(100, 5, .5))
```

Comment: Works nice (though slow), but I can't see a way to define functions in the mapping data frame, e.g. `y = c(mean(x), max(rnorm(x)), x^2...))`.

Comment: @jaySf Yes, obviously it won't be as fast as the `dplyr` solution, but using base R was your requirement. You *can* use functions using `eval(parse(text = ...))`; not pretty, but without knowing what you're trying to do, it's difficult to be more specific. Your question has something of a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, if there are multiple elements to be replaced, create a key/value dataset and do a `merge`

```
keyval <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c("s", "t", "u", "v"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
new <- merge(df1, keyval, by = 'x', all.x = TRUE)[['y']]
new[is.na(new)] <- "w"
df1$x <- new
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rbinom(100, 5, .5))
```

Comment: Thanks, but hen I bind it with `df1$y <- new`, x and y do not match.

Comment: @jaySf  It is matching for me.  We are merging it with a key/value pair .  It should match

Answer (score 1):

I would create an empty vector then fill each condition one by one.

```
df1$y = rep(NA,nrow(df1))
df1$y[x < a] = u(x[x < a])
df1$y[x > a & x < b] = v(x[x > a & x < b])
df1$y[x > b & x < c] = w(x[x > b & x < c])
...
```

I have found this to be the clearest way of setting the values, I find it much easier to see at a glance what is happening when you have more conditions than nested ifelse statements.

```
df1$y = ifelse(x < a, u(x), ifelse(x < b, v(x), ifelse(x < c, w(x), ...)) )
```

An improvement on this would be to predefine the condition elements, that way each group is only calculated once:

```
aEls = which(x < a)
bEls = which(x > a & x < b)
cEls = which(x > b & x < c)
...

y = rep(NA,nrow(df1))
y[aEls] = u(x[aEls])
y[bEls] = v(x[bEls])
y[cEls] = w(x[cEls])
...

df$y = y
```